# Vue.js Setting input value using document.getElementById('id').value does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue js and I want to limit user's input as non-numeric for certain input. So I have implemented it like below.

**Method**

```
preventNonNumeric(id) {
            var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
            if (!(/^\d+$/.test(value))) {
                var newValue = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                document.getElementById(id).value = newValue;
            }
        },
```

**Template Part**

```
<v-autocomplete v-digitsonly :auto-select-one-item=false :label="phoneNumber" :items="drivers" :get-label='getDriverLabel' :component-item='driverTemplate' :wait="0" :min-len="2" @update-items="loadDrivers" @item-selected="selectDriver" :input-attrs="{id: 'driver-phone-number'}" @focus="loadDriverType = 'phoneNumber'" @change="preventNonNumeric('phoneNumber')">
                                    </v-autocomplete>
```

converts to

```
<div data-v-39f1041e="" class="v-autocomplete">
    <div class="v-autocomplete-input-group">
        <input type="search" id="driver-phone-number" class="v-autocomplete-input">
    </div>
</div>
```

`v-autocomplete` comes from https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete. As far as I understand, non-numeric values on input with id `driver-phone-number` should be converted to normal string. However, it only gives me short blink and nothing happens to the value of input field.

Comment: You shouldn't use `getElementById().value` with vue, just use v-model to bind to a variable and use that variable value.

Comment: @XanderLuciano that was exactly my problem. I was forgetting about the two-way binding and using `document.getElementById('searchText').value = ''` instead of the straighforward `this.searchText = ''` (which also updated my input field). Obviously searchText is defined in my app.

Answer (score 0):

this is what your want：

```js
const MyInput = {
  template: '#myInput',
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      inputValue: this.value,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitValue(e) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/\D/g, '');
      this.$emit('input', this.inputValue);     
    }
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {MyInput},
  data () {
    return {
      val: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-input v-model="val"></my-input>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="myInput">
  <input v-model="inputValue" @input="emitValue($event)"/>
</script>
```